# escaping heat differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Heat is escaping at a constant rate through the walls of a long cylindrical pipe.  Find the temp. $T$ at a distance $r$ from the axis of the cylinder if the inside wall has radius $r_0=1$ and temp. $T_0=100$ and the outside wall has $r_1=2$ and $T_1=0$.

Answer (score 0):

http://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/FALL/thermodynamics/notes/node119.html#p3:ConvectionCylinder

With the variables in the problem, we get:

$$T(r) = (T_1-T_0) {\ln({r \over r_0}) \over \ln({r_1 \over r_0 })} + T_0$$

Comment: The correct answer is T= 100[1-(lnr)/(ln2)]...just wondering you you'd get that.